# How to select some data in array structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, select, data-structures

I work in MATLAB environment and I have some structures like this one:

```
>> HTC_01

HTC_01 = 

    Name: 'HTC_One_M8-2015-02-11-15-40-30'
    Date: '2015-02-11'
    Time: [395768x1 double]
      Ax: [395768x1 double]
      Ay: [395768x1 double]
      Az: [395768x1 double]
     Lat: [395768x1 double]
     Lon: [395768x1 double]
     Quo: [395768x1 double]
     Vel: [395768x1 double]
```

Now, I want select some data, e.g., (4646:279745) from all arrays and put the output in a new array with the same name of this one.

I would like obtain:

```
>> HTC_02 = my_resize(HTC_01, 4646, 279745)

HTC_02 = 

    Name: 'HTC_One_M8-2015-02-11-15-40-30'
    Date: '2015-02-11'
    Time: [275100x1 double]
      Ax: [275100x1 double]
      Ay: [275100x1 double]
      Az: [275100x1 double]
     Lat: [275100x1 double]
     Lon: [275100x1 double]
     Quo: [275100x1 double]
     Vel: [275100x1 double]
```

The question is: I must do this one array by array, or there is a more short way to do it?

In my opinion, resize only the arrays is a very simple in MATLAB, so must exist a short way to do it without create a function.

Comment: Select that data and save as what?

Comment: @Divakar A matrix or another array. For me is the same. And thank you.

Comment: How about saving the output data as another variable that is not a structure? That is, where each column would correspond to data from one of the fields?

Comment: Ok: I try to rewrite better my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with only the array fields in the struct:

```
fields = fieldnames(HTC);
i = 1;

for x = 1:length(fields)
    field = fields{x};
    data = getfield(HTC,field);
    if isa(data,'double')
        output(:,i) = data(4646:279745);
        i = i + 1;
    end
end
```

Each data array range required is saved as a column in the output array.

UPDATED AFTER YOUR UPDATE:

```
function output = my_resize(input,r1,r2)

fields = fieldnames(input);
output = input;

for x = 1:length(fields)
    field = fields{x};
    data = getfield(input,field);
    if isa(data,'double')
        output = setfield(output,field,data(r1:r2,1));
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not asked the solution "all inclusive", but thank you again.

Comment: No problem. I decided it was easier to write the solution in code than explain each step. Hopefully it gives you some understanding for similar problems in the feature.

Answer (score 1):

This would be one approach -

```
index_range = 4646:279745                       %// index range
flds = {'Ax','Ay','Az','Lat','Lon','Quo','Vel'} %// fields to be selected
fnames = fieldnames(HTC_01)                     %// all fieldnames

%// Logical array with length as number of fields
%// and ones where the fields to be selected appear
idx = ismember(fnames,flds) 

C = struct2cell(HTC_01) %// Get all of the data into a cell array
out1 = reshape([C{idx}],[],sum(idx)).'          %//'#select fields
out2 = out1(:,index_range)                      %//  select data from range
cell_out = mat2cell(out2,ones(1,size(out2,1)),size(out2,2))

%// Store truncated data into numeric fields and then save back as struct
C(idx) = cell_out
out = cell2struct(C,fnames,1)
```